# Gaussian processes and kernels

Tags: regression, probability, nonparametric, nonlinear-regression

What is the difference between Gaussian process regression and non-parametric regression using kernels?
I think that there is some connection between the two, however my main question is if we can derive  one from the other?

Thanks